# HTML dropdown element disappears after clicking

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular's ng-init to load a rest call function and it fills up $scope.races then it fills up the dropdown.

At first load everything seems fine. But when I click the dropdown menu and select an option. Dropdown immediately becomes empty.

I assume someway $scope.races becomes empty.

This is my Angular controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('RestController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getRaces = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/races').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.races = data;
        });
    }
});
```

This is HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="restController.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="RestController">
<div class="container-fluid" ng-init="getRaces()">
    <select ng-model="races">
        <option ng-repeat="race in races" value="{{race.raceId}}">{{race.raceName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is ng-model="races" on your select is over-writing the $scope.races in your restController.js as soon as you select an option. Rename ng-model="races" to something like ng-model="racesSelection" and use this as the variable to determine what option was selected

Answer (score 2):

Remove ng-model="races", as you are re setting it in . Here is working sample.

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="restController.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="RestController">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-init="getRaces()">
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="race in races" value="{{race.raceId}}">{{race.raceName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script>
    angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('RestController', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.getRaces = function() {
        var data = [{raceId:'1',raceName:'nam1'},{raceId:'12',raceName:'nam2'},{raceId:'13',raceName:'nam13'}];//get data from http
        $scope.races = data;
          // $http.get('http://localhost:8080/races').
          // success(function(data) {
          //     $scope.races = data;
          // });
      }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```